# how to get a blog feed to phonegap application

Tags: html, cordova

Hi I have a phonegap app to create but I am not sure if I can get a blog feed(From a different website) into the app.
I have checked online but i get phonegap blog links instead of an answer to this question.
any help at all would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to get the blog feed URL and then use an AJAX call to collected the feed data and load it into a container in your apps html.

Example (using jquery):

```
$.get('BLOG_FEED_URL', function(results) {
  var len = results.length;
  var list = $('SELECTOR_FOR_LIST_CONTAINER');
  for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
    list.append('SOME_MARKUP'+results[i].SOME_VAR+'SOME_MARKUP');
  }
});
```